# To divide 5 pears, 5 apples,5 doughnuts, 5 lollipops, 5 chocolate cats and 5 candy rocks into two unordered piles of 15 objects each?

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to divide 5 pears, 5 apples,5 doughnuts, 5 lollipops, 5 chocolate cats and 5 candy rocks into two unordered piles of 15 objects each?
Here there are total 30 objects which is to be divided into 2 piles so need help as I am not able to find the method I should use here.

Answer (score 1):

So it is like picking 6 non-negative integers smaller than 6 with the sum of 15. Each number represents how many of each candy is in the first pile.

If you didn't have the limitation "smaller than six" it would be ${15+6-1}\choose{6-1}$, now you have to subtract the cases when there are more than 5 pieces of a candy there.

By using inclusion-exclusion, you subtract cases when some particular kind has at least 6 pieces and then add cases when two of the kinds have at least 6 pieces.

It is ${15+6-1 \choose 6-1}-6\cdot  {9+6-1 \choose 6-1}+{6 \choose 2}{3+6-1 \choose 6-1}$

(Multipliers 6 and ${6 \choose 2}$ are number of ways to pick the kinds with more than 5 pieces)

Comment: Is this the final answer ? The question is for two unordered piles.

Comment: This is the correct answer if the piles are labeled.  However, if the piles are not labeled, we must divide by $2$ since selecting a particular set of objects determines the same two piles as selecting its complement.

Comment: That what N. F. Taussig said